# Return a collection of objects with the same date (MongoDB/Mongoose)

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

Given a collection looking like this

```
{ "uuid" : "32645503-0d51-4fc6-8e4a-28b03714db5e", "date" : "1593701241361" }
{ "uuid" : "63022d8b-e16e-4387-b5c0-74d09a95fb72", "date" : "1593787041640" }
```

where `date` is a date in the format of a number, what would the query look like to get all documents with the same day? It should be very fast/efficient, because my collection has more than 100 000 documents.

Comment: Same day or same date ?

Comment: Same day as said

Comment: Please checkout my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `$toDate` and `$dateToString` mongodb operators to achieve what you want.

Here is the query which finds all the duplicates:

```js
collection.aggregate([{
  // This stage converts dateNumber to dateObject
  $addFields: {
    dateString: { $toDate: "$date" }
  }
}, {
  // This stage converts dateObject to date day
  $addFields: {
    day: { $dateToString: { format: "%Y-%m-%d", date: "$dateString" } }
  }
}, {
  // This stage groups all the records with same day
  $group: {
    _id: { day: "$day" },
    uniqueRecords: { $addToSet: "$_uuid" },
    count: { $sum: 1 }
  }
}, {
  // This stage finds groups which have more than 1 record. (Which means duplication)
  $match: {
    count: { $gt: 1 }
  }
}])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `moment` to convert them into a date format.

```
let epoch = 1593787041640;
let result = moment(epoch).format('DD/MM/YY');
```

Then you can iterate and compare two strings.

and get matching data in return.

Comment: Yes, thats what I use now. But it is just not fast enough with a lot of documents. I am looking for a query command or a db.aggregate to get it done faster. And I dont want do query all documents, but just the ones with the current day.